# how to remove indent from twently eleven comments reply

Tags: comments

how i can remove indent from comments reply if someone reply comments it indent to previous reply and keep adding indent..how i can make it just indent first reply and other show under this..

i searched for solution on google and stackexchange but could't find any..its output simple ordered list for comments and reply to comments with different classes added to list

HTML OF COMMENTS

```
<ol>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is a **CSS** question, not a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of threading completely you can control it in `Settings` > `Discussion` > `Other comment settings` > `Enable threaded (nested) comments`.

If you want to keep functionality and markup, but change it visually you would need to do that via CSS, which (as per comment on your question) is not really WordPress-specific.

Comment: Thanks Rarst, got it working unchecking enable threaded comments :)